# Ways to further simply recursive relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation

I was working on a power series solution in my ODE class and I had found that my $a_n$ seemed to be defined as

$$a_n=\frac{a_o}{(n^{2}(n-1)^{2}…(n-(n+2))^{2}}$$

but I am having trouble understanding if it will hold because I will get zero on the bottom sometimes , so how can I account for this? Or will that be fine since I define this for $n \ge 2?$

Also, is there a more general form that I could put this in, say involving factorials or something ?
Because I had thought maybe my answer could have as part of its form something such as $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n$$

$$a_2=\frac{a_o}{4}$$

$$a_3=\frac{a_o}{(9)(4)}$$

$$a_4=\frac{a_o}{(16)(9)(4)}$$

So how could I write this better/correct?

Thanks

Comment: $$a_n = \frac{a_0}{n!^2} $$

Comment: Thank you. Do you think If I left it the way I had would still be equivlent/correct?

Comment: Yes.  ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That product in the denominator
can not go up to
$n+2$,
because that would make the
denominator zero.

If it goes up to
$n-1$ or $n-2$,
that would be fine.

The series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n!)^2}
$
is a scaled version
of the modified Bessel function
of order zero,
$I_0(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(n!)^2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n}
$.

Look here for more:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

Comment: Oh nice catch ,thanks

Comment: PS: Do you have any other extra links to something discussing the modified Bessel function of order zero, ideally the one you wrote about (the scaled version)?

Comment: For a start, just do a search. Then there is always Watson's classic "A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions".